# assigning value to a parameter using select statment in Stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, parameters

```
Go
Alter procedure usp_ReportUpdates

AS
 Declare  @currentweek as varchar(255), @previousweek varchar(255)

 set @currentweek SELECT distinct fiscalweekqtr from fiscaltime where fiscalweekago=0;
  set @previousweek SELECT distinct fiscalweekqtr   from fiscaltime where fiscalweekago=1;
```

this code gives syntax error at the select work. How else do i assign the singular result of the select query to @currentweek and @previousweek ?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
SELECT @currentweek = fiscalweekqtr from fiscaltime where fiscalweekago=0; 
SELECT @previousweek = fiscalweekqtr from fiscaltime where fiscalweekago=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like SQL Server syntax.  If so, I think this is what you might be looking for:

```
Alter procedure usp_ReportUpdates
AS
BEGIN
    Declare @currentweek as varchar(255),
            @previousweek varchar(255);

    SELECT @currentweek = fiscalweekqtr from fiscaltime where fiscalweekago = 0;
    SELECT @previousweek = fiscalweekqtr from fiscaltime where fiscalweekago = 1;
END;
```

You seem to be missing a condition on the query for `@previousweek`.  That should be filled in as appropriate.

Your particular syntax error is because the `select` statements are subqueries, so should be in parentheses.  However, you don't need subqueries for this statement, as shown above.